# How to add another user to Jenkins X once it has been set up

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, jenkins-x

I have my Jenkins X setup fresh (for example using `jx create cluster gke`) and it works great for me.

How do I add another user to work with it (on their own machine)?

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins X uses Kubernetes permissions, so the new user will need to be setup to access the cluster.

This is currently documented here: 
https://jenkins-x.io/faq/setup/#how-do-i-add-a-user-to-my-jenkins-x-installation